# is it ok for composite primary key to have foreign key refer to parent table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

this is a database for small village for issuing building permits for it's citizens

parent table: **Building Permit**

- permit_id (PK)
- initiate_date
- citizenID
- etc

child table: **Decision sessions**

- session #NO( since EACH Building Permit could have N number of sessions starting from 1 for each permit )
- session date
- decision text
- permit_id (FK)

for child table : should i

1. give it an auto generated integer primary key and name it (eg sessionID).

or

2. choose both (session #NO and permit_id ) as composite primary key.

i don't know if the second solution is valid one from db design prospective.

Comment: The second solution is perfectly valid in the technical aspect, and also from the database desing aspect. Now, which solution you adopt depends entirely on the business model you want to achieve.

Comment: As is often the case, it depends. Both are valid approaches and there are pros and cons to each. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5431/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key-differences-and-when-to-use-in-sql-server/

Comment: great my only concern was trying to save storage by using the two already allocated columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically speaking you are better off with a single field pk over a composite. The only real reason for making a composite would be if you need that extra field to ensure uniqueness. If you are going to have an autonumber field in child table then you already have a field that is guaranteed to be unique for each record. That is sufficient for creating whatever kind of table joins are necessary. In this scenario, creating the pk as a composite key just adds complexity without any real benefit. There are times when a composite key does make sense, but I don't see any valid reason for making one here.

Comment: yes i will go with the first option since other potential tables will be associated with the child table.